# Redirection not working with JQuery Mobile

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile

I am running a DNN7.1 website. I have a regular website. I added a page which acts as login page for mobile users. I am using JQuery Mobile 1.3.2 on the mobile pages including this mobile login page. If the user navigates to that page and enters username and password, it works correctly and redirects them to the correct page sent on the url using a querystring, example:

```
http://localhost/Mobilelogin?url=http://localhost/somePage
```

it correctly redirects to

```
http://localhost/somePage
```

Now I want to add capability where user can directly send his username and password along with the url that he wants to navigate, the login page should authenticate using the username and password provided and once successful redirect it to the url (using asp.net Response.Redirect method), in the format

```
http://localhost/Mobilelogin?u=username&p=password&url=http://localhost/somePage
```

The issue is, it works fine if the user is not logged in but if he is already logged in and then uses the same url, (which has username and password) redirection doesn't work. I tried disabling the ajax using following code, as I read redirection and JQM doesn't work well.

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
$.extend($.mobile, {
linkBindingEnabled: false,
ajaxEnabled: false
});
});
```

But it still is not working. Can anyone please let me know what I need to do to make this work.

I tried debugging the login module, which is written in c#, when the user enters the url when not logged in, it calls the page load and hits the break point but when logged in and enters the url the break point is never hit. It looks like browser is not even contacting the server. I am new to JQM, I thought disabling the ajax globally will always hit the server to get the information. Is that not how it works?  How can I make the redirection work in my case. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have a login page on an **unencrypted** connection?! That's bad enough, but then you want people to pass usernames and passwords in the URL? You might as well just hand your website over to hackers.

Please look up some basic security stuff before proceeding any further.

Comment: While this doesn't really solve the problem, msm8bball is correct - you simply cannot pass usernames and passwords in the URL, and your login page should be secured by SSL as it is handling security information.

Comment: I do know that passing usernames and passwords in url is not secure but we are testing something out for a demo and test server doesn't have a SSL certificate applied. This will not go in a production.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be aware that by default, jQuery Mobile uses AJAX to load page content and does not "redirect" as per normal.

You should read the FAQ's as these provide useful information: -

http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/faq/

Specifically: -

> .. it will only inject the contents of the response's body element (or
>   more specifically the data-role="page" element, if it's provided),
>   meaning nothing in the head of the page will be used

http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/faq/scripts-and-styles-not-loading.html

This might explain why your script doesn't execute, as if it's in the `<head>` it's not being loaded.

Comment: Thank you for the faq link, it helped me with figuring out some other issue I had. The redirection issue was due to error in my code, which was doing a redirection before getting to the MobileLogin page when user is already authorized.

Comment: You're welcome. There's plenty of good third-party resources on the jQuery Mobile site which are all worth looking at.